# How to find an content length int in http header file

Tags: python, http, networking

I am trying to find the integer for content length in a headers file. We are currently using something that works for some websites, but will not work for larger files (over 9999 bytes). How could we find the newline at the end of that specific header so that we can get exactly the integer for content length?

```
content_length = headers[headers.find("Content-Length: ")+16:headers.find("Content-Length: ")+20]
```

I would try searching for the "\r\n" but that is problematic as there are many in the http headers. Unfortunately, we do not have access to urllib.

Example headers:

```
GET http://example.com/ HTTP/1.1\r\n
Content-Length: 95972\r\n
Keep-Alive: 300\r\n
Connection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n
```

Comment: The header names are case insensitive. Just sayin

Comment: What about regular expression search for the Content-Length?

Comment: There are two calls to `headers.find` in your example code.  But you couldn't generalize this to finding the newline you need to find?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple. Assuming your headers are stored to a string:

```
for line in headers:
    if "Content-Length:" in line:
        contentLength = line

contentLength = contentLength[16:]
```

Caveats: Not all HTTP headers contain Content-Length and some headers may contain more than one Content-Length.

Comment: This breaks if "Content-Length" appears again later in the header (for example, as the value of a cookie).

Comment: This is a completely valid caveat as well, did not think about cookies.

Answer (score 0):

Headers ends with "\r\n" not alone "\n". Please read RFC for HTTP.

So, you should read Content-Length header until you hit character "\r", then you can check next character will be "\n" for confirmation.

Or regular expression can be: "Content-Length:\s+\d+\s+"

**EDIT**
Yes there can be many "\r\n" in body, but you don't have to parse all, you just have to iterate over header lines which are separated with "\r\n", and get line that starts as "Content-Length", that's what you are looking for. Additionally, the HTTP message body will start after "\r\n\r\n".

Comment: That was a simple typo due to my use of Linux. In any case, each line has a carriage return and since content length could be any length, we can't just strip it out. That brings me back to the question I asked.